# Extract specific information from a list of dataframes

Tags: r

I am facing the following challenge:

I have a list of dataframes in R and I'd like to extract some specific information from it. Here is an example:

```
df_1 <- data.frame(A = c(1,2), B = c(3,4), D = c(5,6))
df_2 <- data.frame(A = c(7,8), B = c(9,10), D = c(11,12))
df_3 <- data.frame(A = c(0,1), B = c(2,3), D = c(4,5))

L <- list(df_1, df_2, df_3)
```

What I'd like to extract are the values at position (1,1) in each of these dataframes. In the above case this would be: 1, 7, 0.

Is there a way to extract this information easily, probably with one line of code?

Comment: `lapply(L, function(x) x[1, 1])`? or with `sapply`, `sapply(L, function(x) x[1, 1])`. Another way : `sapply(L, `[`, 1, 1)`.

Comment: Or in one line (after creating the data frames): `res <- lapply(list(df_1,df_2,df_3), function(x) x[1, 1])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ronak has suggested , you can use function like lapply and wrap it with unlist for desired output.

```
 unlist(lapply(L,function(x) x[1,1]))
```

Comment: `unlist(lapply(...` = `sapply`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the `*apply` methods shown above, you can also do this in a Vectorized manner. Since all the data frames in your list have the same column names, and you want the first element from the first column, i.e. 'A1', then you can simply `unlist` (which will create a named vector) and grab the values with the name `A1`.

```
v1 <- unlist(L)
v1[names(v1) == 'A1']
#A1 A1 A1 
# 1  7  0
```